# Credentials (Certificate) in ssg-wsg authentication

Tags: certificate

I have uploaded the certificate in my app in developer ssg, how will I mock this using postman and how will I pass the certificate. There are 2 authentications right, open and certificate, I am using certificate and already uploaded the cert.pem in my App but I don't know how to use that and how to mock call the API I added. It was Grant Calculator - Individual.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me on how to integrate this.